# How can I replace automatically-generated grand total values with different ones (Aspose Cells)?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, aspose-cells

My spreadsheet automatically generates a "Grand Totals" column as the rightmost column:

[image]

This is nice, in general. But in specific, I've got a couple of problems with it: The last two values (with the unfortunate labels "Sum of Avg Price" and "Sum of Percentage") provide just that - a sum of the previous columns. In those cases, I don't want a simple sum, but an average in the first case and a percentage in the second case.

For the AvgPrice, what I need is a calculation of "Sum of Total Price" / "Sum of Total Quty" in the Grand Total column. For instance, the first AvgPrice Grand Total value should be "33.14" rather than "66.26"

For the Percentage, I need the percentage of Total Price for the item/Description (such as "25151.75" seen in the first item above) as compared to the "Total Price" value in the "Total Sum of Total Price" grand total row/column ("1529802.82"). That value is seen here:

[image]

So the "Percentage" value for that first item ("ASPARAGUS, LARGE 11/1#") should be approximately 1.6 (as 25151.75 is about 1/60th of 1529802.82), rather than 1.36.

Is there a way to set this up to automatically generate those values in the Grand Total Column, or do I need to prevent the Grand Total column from being generated like so:

```
pivotTable.ColumnGrand = false;
```

...and then add that column to the sheet manually, doing the calculations in code, and adding those values that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest, I think, to just add that column manually, calculating the necessary values; here's how I'm doing it now (basically the same idea as in Excel Interop - manually adding the Grand Total column):

After the PivotTable code, I call AddManualGrandTotalColumn(), which is:

```
private void AddManualGrandTotalColumn()
{
    var pivot = pivotTableSheet.PivotTables[0];
    var dataBodyRange = pivot.DataBodyRange;
    int rowsUsed = dataBodyRange.EndRow;
    int FIRST_DATA_ROW = 7;
    int currentQtyRow = FIRST_DATA_ROW;
    int ROWS_IN_A_RANGE = 4;

    // Needed?
    pivot.RefreshData();
    pivot.CalculateData();

    // Get Total Sales value, which will be needed for computing the % val
    Cell totalTotalPurchasesCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[rowsUsed - 2, _grandTotalsColumnPivotTable + 1];
    decimal totalTotalPurchases = Convert.ToDecimal(totalTotalPurchasesCell.Value);

    Cell gtLabelCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[6, _grandTotalsColumnPivotTable + 2];
    gtLabelCell.Value = "Grand Total";

    Cell QtyCell = null;
    Cell PriceCell = null;
    Cell AvgPriceCell = null;
    Cell PercentageCell = null;
    while (currentQtyRow < rowsUsed)
    {
        // SumTotalQty
        int qty = GetSumTotalQty(currentQtyRow);
        QtyCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[currentQtyRow, _grandTotalsColumnPivotTable + 2];
        QtyCell.Value = qty;
        // SumTotalPrice
        decimal price = GetSumTotalPrice(currentQtyRow+1);
        PriceCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[currentQtyRow+1, _grandTotalsColumnPivotTable + 2];
        PriceCell.Value = price;
        // Calculate Avg Price (SumTotalPrice / SumTotalQty)
        decimal avg = 0.0M;
        if ((price > 0) && (qty > 0))
        {
            avg = price / qty;
        }
        AvgPriceCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[currentQtyRow+2, _grandTotalsColumnPivotTable + 2];
        AvgPriceCell.Value = avg;
        // Calculate Percentage (totalTotalPurchases / SumTotalPrice?)
        decimal prcntg = 0.0M;
        if ((totalTotalPurchases > 0) && (price > 0)) // ? Right calculation?
        {
            prcntg = totalTotalPurchases / price;
        }
        PercentageCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[currentQtyRow+3, _grandTotalsColumnPivotTable + 2];
        PercentageCell.Value = prcntg;

        currentQtyRow = currentQtyRow + ROWS_IN_A_RANGE;
    }
}

private int GetSumTotalQty(int currentQtyRow)
{
    int FIRST_MONTH_COL = 2;
    int LAST_MONTH_COL = _grandTotalsColumnPivotTable; // - 1;
    int cumulativeQty = 0;
    Cell qtyCell = null;
    for (int i = FIRST_MONTH_COL; i <= LAST_MONTH_COL; i++)
    {
        qtyCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[currentQtyRow, i];
        cumulativeQty = cumulativeQty + Convert.ToInt32(qtyCell.Value);
    }
    return cumulativeQty;
}
```

. . . (etc. for GetSumTotalPrice())

Answer (score 1):

In order to look into this issue in detail, please post your query in Aspose.Cells forum with your sample excel files. You can provide us source excel file, actual output excel file and the expected excel file and sample code. And the screenshot like you provided will also be helpful. Thanks for your cooperation in this regard.

**Aspose.Cells Forum Link:**

https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Excel proper; I do it all in code.

Comment: This thread has been marked as resolved with your provided code.